# Call contract's function

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, function, documentation

I'm new in solidity and blockchain itself.

Typed myself contract for [Voting](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/solidity-by-example.html#voting) in VSCode and tried to figure out how I can run code and research workflow and etc. During researching figured out that for start it's recommened to use Remix so I switched to it

1. How I can run code and call functions like `delegate` or `vote` via Remix?
2. Is there way to run code locally(windows) and compile code on each file save and start up contract and call contract's functions as I mentioned in first question?

Comment: You can use hardhat(https://hardhat.org/) tool for run and test smartcontracts locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using remix you just need to compile (third icon on the left menu) and then deploy the contract in the remix VM (or injected provider like metamask with a testnet) after you deploy you will find the exposed functions.[image: remix ide]

If you want to run your code locally I would reccommend using hardhat, but it require a little bit of javascript to take advantage of all of the features.
Here is the official guide for deploying a contract with [hardhat](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/guides/deploying) and here is the [setup guide](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/getting-started#installation)